# can't build google vulkan sample (textures)

Tags: android, android-ndk, vulkan

I am trying to build the tutorial6 from the google repo, which should draw a triagle with a texture.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vulkan-tutorials

Yet, I can't get it to build and it always gives me this error:

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: ninja: Entering directory `C:\gmmo\android-vulkan-tutorials-master\tutorial06_texture\app\.cxx\Debug\2b51h276\arm64-v8a'
  
  C++ build system [build] failed while executing:
      @echo off
      "C:\\Users\\gmmo\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\cmake\\3.22.1\\bin\\ninja.exe" ^
        -C ^
        "C:\\gmmo\\android-vulkan-tutorials-master\\tutorial06_texture\\app\\.cxx\\Debug\\2b51h276\\arm64-v8a" ^
        vktuts
    from C:\gmmo\android-vulkan-tutorials-master\tutorial06_texture\app
  ninja: error: 'C:/gmmo/android-vulkan-tutorials-master/tutorial06_texture/app/src/main/cpp/shaderc/libs/c++_static/arm64-v8a/libshaderc.a', needed by 'C:/gmmo/android-vulkan-tutorials-master/tutorial06_texture/app/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/2b51h276/obj/arm64-v8a/libvktuts.so', missing and no known rule to make it
```

Apparently other folks are having this issue and the work around was to comment out the 'armeabi-v7a' under the gradle

```
from here:

abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'

change to:

abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
```

which I did but made no difference.

The odd part is that if you download the tutorial 5 (triangle with no textures) it works.

Anyone can give me a suggestion on how to go around this issue? And if you are using 'Android Studio Dolphin' mind pull it and try to build on your end and tell me if you are experimenting the same issue.

thank you.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vulkan-tutorials/issues/28

my android studio info (PC)

```
Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335, built on September 29, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 16
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.intellij.plugins.visualstudiokeymap (213.5744.3)
    GLSL (1.21)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the 'build.gradle' file for the 'shaderc' module, which is located in the 'app/src/main/cpp/shaderc' directory.
2. Find the 'abiFilters' section, which specifies the architectures for which the library should be built.
3. Ensure that all the architectures for which you want to build the application are included in the 'abiFilters' section. For example, if you only want to build for 'arm64-v8a', the 'abiFilters' section should look like this:

   abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
4. Rebuild the Shaderc library by selecting the 'shaderc' module in the 'Project' view, and then clicking on the 'Build' button.
5. Once the Shaderc library has been built, try building the tutorial application again.
6. You may want to try cleaning the project by selecting 'Build' -> 'Clean Project' and rebuild the native code.